# How could I type the symbol of an ideal

Tags: fonts

I wish to type the symbol of an ideal B.

See the link below (I cannot attach a picture since I am new here)
http://kobotis.net/math/ec/ShortNotes/sn_GaloisExtensionOfLocalField.pdf

But it is different from what I will get from `\mathfrak{B}`. How should I type it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 20):

Your symbol is not `\mathfrak{B}`. It's a `\mathfrak{P}`

[image]

Here's the complete list of the uppercase Fraktur letters

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I have misunderstood it for a long time.

Comment: Yeah, speak about confusion in that font, especially between `IJ`, `YN`, `SO` etc., not mentioning the lowercase letters...

Comment: @yo' Don't forget `AU`... shocking!

Answer (score 1):

The symbol in the PDF is a P from Euler Fraktur (eufm10). Use it with `\usepackage{eulervm}`.

Comment: `eulervm` is not for Fraktur.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it does set up the shape, but does not define a math alphabet, or `\mathfrak`.