# How to generate Bourbaki style script font

Tags: fonts

Bourbaki's script font is a little different than the usual ones I see in LaTeX (See Bourbaki's General Topology).
How do I generate this type of font?

For example:

[image]

Comment: This is a "Fraktur" F, `\mathfrak{F}` loading the package `amssymb` (actually `amsfonts` would suffice, but `amssymb` provides many more features).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94839/how-could-i-type-the-symbol-of-an-ideal

Comment: Nope, \mathfrak{F} generates a different font.

Comment: It's just a different style of Fraktur; fonts have some small differences with each other. But that is definitely a Fraktur F.

Comment: @egreg If i'm not mistaken this is the text fraktur of `eufrak`.

Comment: @percuße `amsfonts` *does* use Euler Fraktur.

Comment: This F doesn't match eufrak :(

Comment: `\textfrak{F}` in the package `yfonts` produces something similar (but not exact)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to end this:

If the used font is named in "Bourbaki's General Topology" you can search the internet and use it if it is free and downloadable (I do not know this).

If the font is available as open type font, you can install it on your computer and use it with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

If the font is not available you have to use a font looking similar to this.  As mentioned in the comments it is a fraktur font.  If you have to use pdfLaTeX simply use one of the existing fraktur fonts.